# Javascript popup with a table instead of just text (leafletjs example)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In this leafletjs quickstart guide, under the section titled "Working with popups", if you click the blue marker on the map, a popup shows up with the text "hello". Is it possible to have the popup contain, instead of just text, a table? Like a basic 1x2 html table that would be coded in HTML like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible for a popup to contain a table. I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkeller3/xLL4vdfs/) with a simple test to show this and here's the bindPopup call I used.

```
layer.bindPopup("<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>");
```